# Listing user types with counts and percentages

Tags: mysql

I have a `'users'` table:

```
user_id | prov_platform   | first_name   | last_name
--------|-----------------|--------------|-------------------
1       | Facebook        | Joe          | Bloggs
2       | Facebook        | Sue          | Barker
3       |                 | John         | Doe
4       | Twitter         | John         | Terry
5       | Google          | Angelina     | Jolie
```

And I originally wanted to return a list of all the different social platform types there were in my users table, with counts beside each one - so I came up with this:

```
SELECT
IFNULL(prov_platform, 'Other') AS prov_platform, 
COUNT(*) AS platform_total
FROM users
GROUP BY prov_platform
ORDER BY platform_total DESC
```

Which resulted in this:

```
prov_platform  | platform_total
---------------|-----------------
Facebook       | 2
Twitter        | 1
Google         | 1
Other          | 1
```

But I now want to add another couple of fields to this query; 'allround_total' and 'percentage'. So, the above recordset would become:

```
prov_platform  | platform_total | allround_total | percentage
---------------|----------------|----------------|---------------
Facebook       | 2              | 5              | 40%
Twitter        | 1              | 5              | 20%
Google         | 1              | 5              | 20%
Other          | 1              | 5              | 20%
```

This is as far as I got before getting in a muddle:

```
SELECT
    u.prov_platform, 
    COUNT(*) AS platform_total,
    allround_total,
    allround_total/platform_total*100 AS percentage
FROM
    users AS u
INNER JOIN (
           SELECT COUNT(*) AS allround_total FROM users
           ) AS allround_total
GROUP BY
    prov_platform
ORDER BY
    platform_total DESC
```

This returns the 'allround_total' field, which works, but have no idea how performance friendly it'll be. What I can't workout is how to get the percentage to work correctly. Currently, the above query returns an error:

> Unknown column 'platform_total' in 'field list'

I think I'm close, I just need a much appreciated push over the line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use column aliases in the same level as they are defined.  I also think you have the calculation for percentage backwards.

```
SELECT u.prov_platform, COUNT(*) AS platform_total,
       const.allround_total,
       100*count(*)/const.allround_total AS percentage
FROM users u cross join
     (SELECT COUNT(*) as allround_total FROM users
     ) const
GROUP BY prov_platform
ORDER BY platform_total DESC;
```

I changed the `join` from `inner join` to `cross join`.  Although MySQL allows all joins to lack an `on` clause, I find it disconcerting to see an `inner join` with no `on`.  Similarly, I changed the name of the table alias to differ from the column alias, to make the query easier to read.

Comment: Thank you very much, Gordon, this works a treat. I suppose I was slightly close. I have never seen a CROSS JOIN before, so I'd better get reading about them! Thanks again.

Comment: @PaparazzoKid . . . You were quite close.  The problem in your query was just using the column alias at the same level it was defined.  In MySQL, an `inner join` with no `on` clause is the same as a `cross join`.  The latter is clearer and the ANSI standard syntax.

Comment: Well that saves a read, thanks. I use this syntax quite a lot, so using CROSS JOINS will be very useful :)